# Specs satisfying the `ParseFacebookUtils` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9uG4.png)when I am installing pod file for latest  parse sdk by using the below syntax in podfile:

pod 'Parse'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'

Getting error like  ld: library not found for -lPods

Please help me.

Comment: Anyone Please  help me.

Answer (score 5):

Your podfile should have **platform** same as set in your **Project target->General-> Deployment Info**.
Like if deployment info is set to be 9.0, then add the line to your podfile.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem could happen in the latest React Native 0.63, which I had just experienced. RN 0.63 required iOS 10 or higher. The solution is just `platform :ios` in Podfile to `10` or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue, make sure that every Deployment Target in your project is at least 8.1 for every Project and Target.

This includes Pods > Build Settings > iOS Deployment Target, all Targets there, and your main Project and Targets.